# Swift - how to proceed to decode a local json file if online fetch failed?

Tags: json, swift, async-await

I have a hosted json file online which i fetch and decode with the code below.
And I have a local json file in my Xcode Workspace which should be the fallback file.

Can someone please help me how to change this to use and decode the local file when an error with the hosted file occurs? - e.g. no internet connection, ...

***WineryModel.swift***

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://***/wineries.json")

class WineryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var wineries: [Winery]?
    @Published var currentWinery: Winery?
    
    init(){
        Task{
            do{
                try await fetchJsonData()
            }catch{
                // HANDLE ERROR
                print(" " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Fetching Crypto Data
    func fetchJsonData()async throws{
        // MARK: Using Latest Async/Await
        guard let url = url else{return}
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let response = try await session.data(from: url)
        let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Winery].self, from: response.0)
        
        // Alternative For DispatchQueue Main
        await MainActor.run(body: {
            self.wineries = jsonData
            if let firstWinery = jsonData.first{
                self.currentWinery = firstWinery
            }
        })
    }
}
```

***ContentView.swift***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var wineVM: WineryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let wineries = wineVM.wineries, let currentWinery = wineVM.currentWinery {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(wineries) { winery in
                        Text(winery.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to catch your network error like this:

```
func fetchJsonData()async throws{
    // MARK: Using Latest Async/Await
    guard let url = url else{return}
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    var body: Data
    do {
        body = try await session.data(from: url).0
    } catch {
        // This is where the network error ends
        // Load the file here
        body = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    }
    
    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Winery].self, from: body)
    
    // Alternative For DispatchQueue Main
    await MainActor.run(body: {
        self.wineries = jsonData
        if let firstWinery = jsonData.first{
            self.currentWinery = firstWinery
        }
    })
}
```

So like mentioned, catch the network error using a `do/catch` block and then in the catch block, load the file. Then continue as normal